# Saving Files to SharePoint 2007 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sharepoint

Relatively new Python user here, so please bear with me.  As part of a program I am working on, I need to have Python loop through folders in a SharePoint site, copy a file in each folder, and paste the copies into a local folder.  I am attempting to use shutil.copy, but I'm getting an error ("OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument").  I do not get any errors if I try to copy files from a local drive, leading me to believe SharePoint is the issue.

After doing some research, it appears that I need to install some type of module to work with SharePoint.  Is this accurate?  Even if I normally just use Windows Explorer to navigate/edit files on the SharePoint site?

The other issue is that my work still uses SharePoint 2007, so I think that may limit my options.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

```
import xlrd
import shutil
import os

#This is the location of the file on the SharePoint
sp_file = "https://...test.xlsx"
#This is the desired destination locally.
sp_comp_file = "C:\\Users\\555555\\Desktop\\Python Test\\test.xlsx"
shutil.copy(sp_file, sp_comp_file)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\555555\Desktop\Python\teststack.py", line 9, in <module>
    shutil.copy(sp_file, sp_comp_file)
  File "C:\Users\555555\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 235, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\555555\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 114, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://...test.xlsx'
```

Comment: Please post your code and the complete error output, per usual stack overflow conventions. Thanks

Comment: @Justin Added to the post.

Answer (score 1):

It might be late now, but try to remove the "https:" from your variable called `sp_file` such as:

```
sp_file = "//...test.xlsx"
```

I'm doing the same kind of copy/paste on a SP site and without the "https:" it works for me.
Not sure it will work, because I don't get the same error than you if I add "https:" in my program.